# The simplest circuit to translate from RJ11 to my PC

Tags: telephone, signal-processing

Assuming that you don't want to get a functionality, it doesn't need to be a DSL modem, you want to study some signals and you only need an input starting from an RJ11 and going to a PC; what is the simplest circuit X that you can build for the Y interface/bus that you can usually find on a standard PC ?

for example Y can be:

- USB
- RS232
- RJ45
- SATA ( ? )
- ...

Comment: Tell use more about this "some signal". Is it digital or analog, is it a voltage or a switch, and how fast are the changes that you want to observe?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen well, I would prefer to read something digital in input since it's a PC, the signal that I'm referring to is the DSL signal, or all the signals that get transported by the cable, DSL + voice basically; it depends on how complicated this circuit will be, but I'm interested in the DSL one in the first place.

Comment: in the simplest terms: I would like to do all the signal processing and analysis, like the FFT, on my PC.

Comment: This question makes no sense or is lacking significant important information.  What is on the other side of this RJ-11 that you want to somehow "connect" to a PC?  You say you don't want "a functionality".  If that were really true, then you wouldn't need to connect the PC and the RJ-11 at all.  What kind of information do you want to be able to measure about this signal?  Very important is knowing the upper frequency you care about.  The solution will vary drastically depending on that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop on the other side of the RJ11 there is a phone line, I would like to replicate what a DSL modem does, conversion and modulation of the data, but with a simple circuit + my pc.

Comment: Suggestion: have a look at "softmodems" or "winmodems", in particular this circuit for interfacing to a sound card: http://www.araneus.fi/audsl/hybrid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "study" the signals, and do some FFT stuff on them you must to acquire them, right?

It's a conversion from analog to digital. So, what you need is a ADC that is able to **sample at a frequency** at least twice the highest frequency you want to see (Nyquist theorem), and you need a converter that has a **dynamic range** high enough to not distort the signals (in Volts).

A common used converter used for such DIY project is the audio card. In your case it's not suitable because sampling frequency is too low (44,100 kHz and you need MHz I guess).

So, I think that what you need is a similar to a **scope**, where you can save the acquired data to your PC.

Comment: this is what I want to do http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111548/the-simplest-circuit-to-translate-from-rj11-to-my-pc/111565?noredirect=1#comment223195_111548 . I don't think I can connect 55Volt to my sound card.